# Why are clothes “hung” but men “hanged”?

Tags: etymology, differences, verbs, past-participles

It is said that clothes can be *hung* but men are *hanged*.

Is this correct, and if so, why?

Comment: well, a man can be ‘hung’ too, but it means something entirely different from being ‘hanged’

Comment: Terry Pratchett does a version of this joke, also making fun of 'drawn' and 'quartered'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the OED, the verb *hang* came into English from Old Norse *hengja* with weak inflection (so, taking regular past forms).  Eventually, by analogy with other ablaut forms like *sing/sang/sung*, the verb *hang* changed into a few different forms (depending on the region of England), e.g. *hing/hang*, *hang/hong*, etc. Ultimately, the *hing/hang* form added *hung* to complete the *sing/sang/sung* analogy.

Now here's the important bit, directly from the OED:

> The weak inflexion *hanged* however
>   continued in use (being the only one
>   used in Bible versions from Coverdale
>   to 1611, though Tindale had also
>   houng); but was gradually superseded
>   by *hung* in the general sense, trans.
>   and intr., leaving *hanged* only in the
>   special trans. sense (3) ‘put to death
>   by hanging’, owing prob. to the
>   retention of this archaic form by
>   judges in pronouncing capital
>   sentences. The distinction is found
>   already in Shakespeare, and is
>   established in the objurgatory
>   expressions ‘You be hanged!’ ‘I'll be
>   hanged if I do’, and the like.

(At some point, obviously *hing* fell out of use in Standard English in the present tense form.)

Answer (score 3):

[This old reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=DsQVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=%22to+put+to+death+by+hanging%22&source=bl&ots=OKb5ig_FKp&sig=_UI4GMWTgD8iLD-LSgMz2qL-pKs&hl=en&ei=TbNlTO6RBIH88Aa85oSXCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CDgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20put%20to%20death%20by%20hanging%22&f=false) in the Dictionary of the English Language (thanks, Google Books!) supports the usage you outline as correct.

Grammar Girl [writes](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/hanged-versus-hung) that this is because there are 2 different Old English words for the two meanings:

> […] in Old English there were two different words for hang (hon and hangen), and the entanglement of these words (plus an Old Norse word hengjan) is responsible for there being two past-tense forms of the word hang today (1).

[Quote reference: Burchfield, R. W., ed. *The New Fowler's Modern English Usage*. Third edition. New York: Oxford, 1996, p. 349.]

Comment: Note that your first link gives both a transitive and an intransitive sense for the ‘execution’ *hang*.

Comment: the same is true in German, where participle and past tense differentiate intransitive and transitive, *gehangen, gehängt, ich hing*, *ich hängte* (cf. [Grimm](https://dwds.de/dwb/hängen) in German).This leads to confusion, the intr. being used forvthe transitive, though not vice versa, and similarly for other words, e.g. *gewinkt* or *gewunken*. Legalese tends to be archaic or archaizing and thus retained the difference longer in English I guess, despite the Norse influence, if I might say so, which however surely showed the same dilemma.