# Weaved or woven

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-participles

Is *weaved* an acceptable past-tense form of the word *weave*? Does it have to be *wove/woven* or are both acceptable like *hung/hanged*?

Comment: Side note, "hung" and "hanged" are both correct, but not interchangeable. It depends on the context.
If you hang a picture, then you hung a picture on the wall.
If you hang a person at the gallows then they were hanged. I don't care how old this question is - I just felt inclined to point that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *weaved* is not commonly accepted as a past participle of *weave* (in the meaning of “forming fabric”).

None of the dictionaries I have access to (*NOAD*, [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weave), [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weave)) all report the past participle of *weave* as being either *wove* or *woven*.

On the other hand, the verb *weave* in the less common meaning of “[twist and turn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weave#Verb_2)” is regular. Its past participle is thus *weaved*.

Comment: The OED says "The weak inflection [sc. 'weaved'] has been occasionally used in all periods from the 14th cent. onwards, but has never become general."

Comment: Here's a good example sentence for "weaved":  "The drunk driver weaved in and out of his lane."  Definitely a situation where you would never say "woven."

Comment: @Phoenix - but you could say *wove*

Comment: Also, hung/hanged are not "both acceptable." They mean completely different things. Hanged is only used for the method of executing a human being. Where as anything else can be hung. I.e., "She hanged the clothes to dry," would not be acceptable in that sentence. Also, "After the accused was found guilty of murder, the townspeople hung him" would not be the correct word.

Comment: @Bob: indeed, and there's even a [separate question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/818/why-are-clothes-hung-and-men-hanged) for that.