# Are These Words Interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-tense

"The man was *hung* at dawn." 
"The man was *hanged* at dawn."

Are "hung" and "hanged" entirely interchangeable?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/818

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not entirely interchangeable.

*Hanged* is the correct past participle of *hang = execute*.

*Hung* is the correct past participle of *hang = suspend*. It **is** increasingly used for *hang = execute* as well (possibly as an over-correction as *hanged* is odd), but where there are two words with distinct usages, it's a great pity to confuse them.

Comment: Why is it a pity? There can’t be much doubt over what _The man was hung at dawn_ means.

Comment: Because it reduces diversity and the richness of the language. And while there may be no doubt about what the author of that sentence might have *meant*, it isn't what he *said*. [Body suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28body_modification%29) (not for the faint-hearted!)

Comment: @BarrieEngland I wouldn't have much doubt over what _The curtains were hung at dawn_ meant, but that's exactly how _The man was hung at dawn_ strikes my ear. So I put in with Andrew on this one.

Comment: It's another shibboleth. Nothing more.

Comment: @BarrieEngland That's what this site is for.

Comment: At http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hang : << ... _Hung_ is the normal form in most general uses, e.g. they hung out the washing ... ; but _hanged_ is the form normally used in reference to execution by hanging: the prisoner was hanged. The reason for this distinction is a complex historical one: hanged, the earlier form, was superseded by hung sometime after the 16th century; it is likely that the retention of hanged for the execution sense may have to do with the tendency of archaic forms to remain in the legal language of the courts.>> Sounds shibbolethic to me.